# Window Pop up load testing through jmeter recording

Tags: jmeter

Parent Page: HD FlowSheet
Child Window Pop Up: Pre Dialysis Treatment

To open child window, window.open() function is used.

Now I recorded script and update some value (name, value) by using send parameter with the request feature of jmeter.

Now executed it and analyzed listeners and found every thing is fine with script. But when I went to child window using browser i find same old values. 
please help me know why this script is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably "every thing is fine with script" is not that fine, JMeter automatically treats HTTP Request samplers with [HTTP status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) below `400` as successful.

If you see "green" successful results it doesn't mean that your script is doing what it is supposed to be doing, you might get "stuck" at login page so I would recommend checking requests and responses using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener.

In the absolute majority of cases you cannot just replay recorded script without prior [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) of the dynamic parameters.

Record the same test scenario one more time and compare the scripts, most probably you will see the differences, this dynamic values need to be correlated to wit you will need to:

1. Extract the dynamic value from the previous response using a suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and save it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
2. Replace recorded hard-coded value with the variable from the previous step
3. Repeat for all the dynamic parameters

Check out [How to Handle Correlation in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter/) article for more information and examples.

A couple more things to remember/consider:

- Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan, it deals with cookie-based authentication in particular and represents browser cookies in general
- According to [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

  > JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages**. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

  therefore JMeter will not invoke [Window.open() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) automatically, you will need to add the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler manually.